# how to change date format from values to date in barplot

Tags: r, xts

I want to use barplot() to plot a time series xts object. However, the date format shown up in x axis is in numeric values instead of date format. How can I change the numeric values to date format like "2012-06-12"? Here is an example code:

```
x<-rnorm(100);
y <- xts(x, Sys.Date()+1:100);
barplot(y);
```

Comment: I tried your code on 3 different OSes, and all had dates formatted like you want.  Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question

Comment: Thanks to GSee. My sessionInfo() isR version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                
[5] LC_TIME=C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic solution is to use the `names.arg` argument, but as I said in my comment, I can't reproduce your problem with the code you provided.

```
barplot(y, names.arg=format(index(y), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: I wonder the possible reason may be the locale setup. I don't know.

Comment: @user1461289 Yes it is probably locale. Do you see the dates like you want using the `names.arg` argument per my answer?

Comment: yes, I got the results I want after I followed your suggestions. Thanks for your help.